# Creating common class objects based on class name and use it

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq

I have the same code logic used across different class objects.

For ex:

```
var matchingTypes = from matchType in order.Contacts
                         select matchType;

var matchingTypes = from matchType in customer.Contacts
                         select matchType;
```

Instead of writing duplicate lines of code, i would like to pass order, customer class names and get Contacts through it, so that the above code will look like (we are using LINQ in our code)

```
var matchingTypes = from matchType in objectElement.Contacts
                         select matchType;
```

The stuff i tried is passed an object parameter

```
GetData(object objectElement) // method consuming an object parameter.

var objectOrder= objectElement as Orders;

var objectCustomer= objectElement as Customers;


if(objectOrder!=null)
{

objectElement = (Orders) objectOrder; //type 

}

if(objectCustomer !=null)
{

objectElement = (Customers) objectCustomer;
}
```

By doing so, i am repeating my code, which i would like to avoid, any suggestions/ideas? thanks.

I would like to use objectElement and assign only once, so that i can call like this as shown below

```
var matchingTypes = from matchType in objectElement.Contacts
                         select matchType;
```

Comment: Sounds like you should have an interface (or you could duck-type, but I wouldn't recommend it if you don't have to). What is the type of `matchingTypes` in both cases? Are they the same?

Comment: And why do you have a LINQ statement for what is basically `var matchingTypes = customer.Contacts`?

Comment: We use LINQ in our code from DB context objects.

Comment: So? You are still doing exactly the same as `var matchingTypes = customer.Contacts`.

Comment: Contacts is a linked table entity object which has relationship with orders and customers ie. orders and customer tables have foreign keys with contacts table, so at run time, based on whether the call is invoked by orders/customers, i would want to do it in a common way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An interface would be the preferred way to do this, but you could also use `dynamic` to duck type a method:

```
public IEnumerable<Contact> GetContacts(dynamic yourObject) 
{
    return yourObject.Contacts;
}
```

Note this will not give you a compile error if you call it with something that doesn't have a property called `Contacts` of type `IEnumerable<Contact>` but will instead give you a runtime error.

Or you don't even actually need a method, you could just do this:

```
var matchedTypes = ((dynamic)yourObject).Contacts as IEnumerable<Contact>;
```

Interfaces would be a safer bet, but are a little tricky with generate entity framework classes. But you can do them becuase they are generated as `partial` classes. So you can do something like this:

```
public interface IHaveContacts
{
    public IEnumerable<Contact> Contacts { get; }
}
```

and then:

```
public partial class Orders : IHaveContacts
{
     // should need to do anything since the auto-genrated Contacts property
     // will satisfy the interface
}

public partial class Customers : IHaveContacts
{
     // ditto
}
```

And now you can do:

```
var matchedTypes = ((IHaveContacts)yourObject).Contacts;
```

Or, if you *really, really* must (which you don't):

```
var matchedTypes = from matchType in ((IHaveContacts)yourObject).Contacts
                   select matchType;
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an interface IContactsContainer:

```
public interface IContactsContainer
{
     public YourContactType Contacts{get;set;}
}
```

Then your customer and order classes can implement it:

```
public class Customers : IContactsContainer
{
     public YourContactType Contacts {get;set;}
     ....
}

public class Orders: IContactsContainer
{
     public YourContactType Contacts {get;set;}
     ....
}
```

After that in your method you can use:

```
IContactsContainer objectElement = yourOrderObject;
```

Comment: Since it's called `Contacts`, it would be a pretty safe bet that it's a collection.

Comment: @MattBurland Also, the LINQ statement in OP's question wouldn't work if it wasn't a collection or `IQueryable`.